# jsf application in tomcat cluster with session replication

Tags: java, jsf, tomcat, cluster-computing

We have a jsf2 application in a tomcat clustering environment with session replication via SimpleTcp.

When the balancer (mod_jk) changes the node we have an typical viewExpiredException.

It seems not properly serialized jsf view state... any configuration suggestions?

Thanks!

Jose.

Comment: What is your <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name> in you web.xml?

Comment: the state saving method is **server**, if we change to **client** works! but we don´t want to change it.

Comment: we are using Mojarra and also tried whit **com.sun.faces.serializeServerState=true** but does not work

Comment: Well I didn't know that. Is there a possibility for you to use sticky sessions?

Comment: Is not the idea. The goal is a replica of the session and balance without sticky sessions. 

So if a node fails or not the other must respond and recover objects in the session, as the view state.

Comment: Considered using an application server designed for clustering?

Comment: Any updates about this problem? I'm using WAS 8.0 and suffering from the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Hi This topic is very old and by the time the problem may be solved. Still i want to answer it for other users.

The problem is with the View State Encryption. Every time a JSF application is deployed it creates a encryption key, by which it encrypt the view-state. And it is obvious that two seperate instance of tomcat generates to different key and the state is not recognized by other node.

[See this Link for details of configuration for myfaces](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MYFACES2/Secure+Your+Application)